# How do I get all of the table names in a SSIS package?

Tags: ssis, tablename

I am working on a migration project to Azure.  I have tried to search the internet with no avail. beside accessing the table name via the XML.

Comment: Can I find the source tables in the SSDT in the Control Flow?

Answer (score 1):

Your biggest challenge will be how clever previous developers were. A table name may be specified as a hard coded value - easy or an SSIS Variable - hard.

Why is the variable approach hard? I could have `CurrentTableName` and the value in the xml specifies `table20180317`. But there could be an expression on that variable that really makes the table name tableYYYYMMDD and when the package runs, it evaluates to table20191212. If no expression is set, then you still have to worry about Expression Tasks (2012+), Script Tasks and command line property overrides.

Since you haven't specified what the team/you are going to be good at using tool-wise, nor how complex the packages are, it's hard to say propose a best approach for resolving this. Personally, I would look at adding the free [BimlExpress](http://varigence.com/bimlexpress) plugin to your Visual Studio/SSDT instance. I'd then reverse engineer the SSIS packages into Biml. Biml is an XML dialect that simplifies package creation and inspection. Instead of all the xml cruft that a .dtsx package contains, the attributes in the Biml representation of a package is going to be much simplier.

From there, I'd either hand inspect the Biml if the number of packages is something small. If something larger, I'd use Linq and the Biml object model to enumerate through the packages and build out a list of all the user defined variables, connection strings, the SQL from any Execute SQL Task and then the sources and sinks of a data flow along with which connection manager it uses and the target table/variable.